# Import .kml map points to ARCore

Tags: arcore

Before I go down the rabbit hole of learning a new language, I'd like to know if what I want is possible.

I've just seen the Google maps augmented reality ARCore working and have a perfect project in mind.  I have an existing `.kml` file containing map points all over Paris.

I'd like to import them into an ARcore project/android app so I can turn it on and it tells me the nearest map point overlayed on the camera, with directions from my current location.

My (very limited) research tells me most of this is possible, but I can't find any info about importing map points from kml files.  Would I have to import every point manually?